# Background Process not running?

Tags: process, background-process

I ran a C program with an infinite while loop in a terminal and observed one of the CPU cores shot to 100% usage. When I turn it into a background process using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>, the CPU usage suddenly dipped to < 10%. Using `htop`, I found that the process was using 0% of the CPU. What has happened to the process?

The program

```
int main()
{
    int i;
     while( 1 )
    { }
    return 0;
}
```

Since there is no I/O involved in the program, I made small changes to the program to see if the I/O wait increased the usage, but got the same results (0% usage).

```
int main()
{
    int i;
     while( i+1 ) // wait to retrieve i
    {
        i = 1; 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What has happened to the process ? Is it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> in your terminal, a SIGTSTP is sent to the process group of the task running in the foreground.

The default action of SIGSTP is to stop (i.e. suspend) the process:

```
     18    SIGTSTP      stop process         stop signal generated from keyboard
```

If you want the process to resume operation in the background, you can use the shell-builtin `bg` (short for background).  If you want the process to resume operation in the foreground, you can use the `fg` command.